# Problema con ciclo en python

Tags: python

Buenas tardes me podrian ayudar con este codigo por favor:

```
try:

numero1=int(input("Digite el primer numero entero:"))

numero2=int(input("Digite el segundo numero entero:"))


    for i in range(numero1+1,numero2,1):
        if i % 5 == 0:
            print(i)

        else:
            print("No hay multiplos de 5 comprendidos entre ambos numeros") 
            break       

    for l in range(numero2+1,numero1,1):
        if l % 5 == 0:
            print(l)

        else:
            print("No hay multiplos de 5 comprendidos entre ambos numeros")     
            break

except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
```

sin importar que numeros ingrese siempre me imprime lo que hay en el else, y si borro los dos "else" el programa si funciona pero queda incompleto porque tambien necesito que me diga cuando no se cumpla lo del "if"

Comment: Está rompiendo el ciclo en la primera iteración con el break...

Comment: Andress155 por favor formatea el código correctamente, copialo, lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor. Si se pierde la identación en Python tenemos un problema. Por otro lado, las etiquetas Python 3 y Python 2.7 no deberían ir juntas, ese código es para Python 3. Por otro lado no se debe forzar las etiquetas en el título (sobra lo de "en python", para eso están las etiquetas) y falta una descripción de lo que debería hacer el código. No hay problema con que reviertas mi edición, pero mejora la pregunta en tal caso... Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes mal son las sentencias `break`, eso hace que salga del for.
Lo segundo que está mal es que recorres el bucle dos veces, una de menor a mayor y otra de mayor a menor.
Aquí te pongo el código arreglado:

```
try:
    numero1=int(input("Digite el primer numero entero: "))
    numero2=int(input("Digite el segundo numero entero: "))
    multiplos = list()

    for i in range(numero1+1,numero2):
        if i % 5 == 0:
            multiplos.append(i)
    if multiplos: #Si stá vacía es False
        print("\nLos números múltiplos de 5 entre "+str(numero1)+" y "+str(numero2)+": ")
        print(multiplos)
    else:
        print("No hay multiplos de 5 comprendidos entre ambos numeros")
except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
```

Para evitar que se muestre por pantalla el mensaje: **No hay multiplos de 5 comprendidos entre ambos numeros** he creado una lista que hará más limpia la salida.

También, cuandogeneras un `range(from,to)` por defecto los números son de 1 en 1, no hace falta indicarle que vaya de 1 en 1 como lo tenías puesto, a no ser que quieras que los genere en otro orden.

saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias amigo de verdad me has salvado

Comment: Nada, es un placer!

Answer (score 0):

no es necesario usar el ciclo for, ya que el número empieza a recorrer la función, por ejemplo, si ingresas 5 y 3, hará un recorrido 8 veces y te mostrará 7 veces que no es múltiplo del 5 y 1 vez que si.
la solución es:

```
try:

  numero1=int(input("Digite el primer numero entero:"))
    if i % 5 == 0:
        print(i)

    else:
        print("No hay multiplos de 5 comprendidos entre ambos numeros") 

    if l % 5 == 0:
        print(l)

    else:
        print("No hay multiplos de 5 comprendidos entre ambos numeros")
```

Comment: Ese código es totalmente diferente al que andrés ha preguntado, en el tuyo solo compruebas si es múltiplo de 5 y lista, sin tener en cuenta que no utilizas la cláusula `except` y que no has declarado la variable `l`